# How avoid explicit casting

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a problem writing a function that takes an argument of type `Any?` and needs to pass it to a `CriteriaBuilder` method that expects `Comparable` types.

```
val arg : Any? = args.first()
return when (operator) {
            EQUAL -> criteriaBuilder.equalPredicate(arg, root)
            GREATER_THAN -> criteriaBuilder.greaterThanPredicate<Comparable<Comparable<*>>>(arg, root)
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown comparison operator: $operator")
        }


private fun <Y : Comparable<Y>> CriteriaBuilder.greaterThanPredicate(arg: Any?, root: Root<T>) : Predicate {
        check(arg != null, { "Cannot compare null arguments" })
        return when (arg) {
            is Comparable<*> -> greaterThan(root.get(property), arg as Y)
            else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot process comparation of: $arg of class ${arg.javaClass}")
        }
    }
```

This solution actually "works" but it has the following problems:

1) I have to cast `arg as Y` without knowing if arg is actually a Comparable type that respects the assertion: "I'm an object of a type A that is `Comparable<A>`".

2) Since it is impossible to infer the type parameter Y, I have to explicitly set it during the method call. By the way I have to insert an ugly `Comparable<Comparable<*>>` that doesn't respect the contract that I want to assert. A `data class A : Comparable<B>` passes that assertion but I want a class like `data class A: Comparable<A>`.

Can someone help me to understand how unlock this situation? :)

Comment: Would doing a [safe cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) be helpful here?

Comment: "I have a problem writing a function that takes an argument of type Any?" In general the only option is to have a layer which checks that the `Any?` argument is the expect type and then casts, before  calling safer typed functions. Also consider if you really need the `Any?` in the first place. If you control the code which returns the `Any?` you should be able to get rid of it.

Comment: @PiRocks Sadly I don't have any control over the ```Any?``` variable since it is returned from an external library. The real problem here is that there is no way (or at least I can't find it) to check if ```Any?``` implements ```Comparable<OfHisSameType>```. Have you any idea how can I check this?

Comment: Unfortunately you can only check for Comparable<*> , because of java type erasure. You could however wrap it in another type which implements Comparable<OfHisSameType>, and delegates the comparison with casting. That way you don't have to cast all over your code base.

Comment: Do you need to support any arbitrary kind of Comparable, or just the primitive number types?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I want to support any arbitraty kind of Comparable.

Comment: @PiRocks the problem is that I have no idea which kinds of Comparable will reach this kind of code... try to think at that snippet like if it was a part of a library. I don't know which kind of entity my framework will discover and all the current and future types.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to declare `arg`'s type as `Y`. Then you know `arg` is a non-null `Comparable<Y>`, so you will not have to check if it's null or is comparable, and the type of your function can be inferred from the argument you pass when you call it.

```
fun <Y : Comparable<Y>> CriteriaBuilder.greaterThanPredicate(arg: Y, root: Root<T>) : Predicate {
    return greaterThan(root.get(property), arg)
}
```

You will still have to do a cast, because you are making an assumption based on runtime values that there's no way the compiler can check. But you can at least move the cast to the place where you are making the assumption, and do a safe check there.

```
val arg : Any? = args.first()
return when (operator) {
            EQUAL -> criteriaBuilder.equalPredicate(arg, root)
            GREATER_THAN -> {
                (arg as? Comparable<Int>) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Unsupported or missing argument")
                criteriaBuilder.greaterThanPredicate(arg, root)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown comparison operator: $operator")
        }
```

If you're supporting multiple comparable types, you may need to enumerate them:

```
val arg : Any? = args.first()
return when (operator) {
            EQUAL -> criteriaBuilder.equalPredicate(arg, root)
            GREATER_THAN -> when {
                arg is Int -> criteriaBuilder.greaterThanPredicate(arg, root)
                arg is Double -> criteriaBuilder.greaterThanPredicate(arg, root)
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unsupported or missing argument")
            }
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown comparison operator: $operator")
        }
```

Comment: You have almost "centered" my problem! I want to check (obv better with safe cast) if arg is of type ```Y:Comparable<Y>``` and then pass it to the function.
By the way I have no idea how to write it. For example writing ```arg as? Comparable<Int>``` doesn't check the ```Y:Comparable<Y>``` condition (i.e. ```class A : Comparable<Int>``` satisfied it, but A cannot compare other items of type A)

Comment: This is tricky. I'm not sure at first look how to do that more cleanly than you have it. But what you have is checking `Comparable<*>` so it could make an incorrect assumption that `arg` is actually comparable to whatever `Y` is.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer to my own question.
I don't know if using reflection in this case is worth or a good practice, but I guess this snippet solve the posted problem.

```
data class ClassInterfaces(val clazz: Class<*>, val interfaces: List<Class<*>>)

private fun extractClassTree(arg: Any): List<Class<*>> =
    extractClassTree(arg::class.java, mutableListOf())

private fun extractClassTree(clazz: Class<*>, seen: MutableList<Class<*>>): List<Class<*>> {
    val classesToCheck = listOf(*clazz.interfaces, clazz.superclass).filterNotNull()
    return listOf(clazz,
        *classesToCheck
            .filter { seen.contains(it).not() }
            .onEach { seen.add(it) }
            .flatMap { extractClassTree(it, seen) }
            .toTypedArray()
    )
}

fun checkIfComparableOfSameType(arg: Any) = extractClassTree(arg)
    .any { checkIfcomparableOfSameType(it) }


fun checkIfcomparableOfSameType(clazz: Class<*>): Boolean {
    val comparableType = clazz
        .annotatedInterfaces
        .map { it.type as? ParameterizedType }.filterNotNull()
        .find { it.rawType == Comparable::class.java }
        ?.actualTypeArguments
        ?.first()
    return when (comparableType) {
        is ParameterizedType -> comparableType.rawType == clazz
        else -> comparableType == clazz
    }
}
```

Then I can safely cast in my method:

```
private inline fun <reified Y : Comparable<Y>> CriteriaBuilder.comparablePredicate(
        operator: ComparisonOperator, arg: Any?, root: Root<T>
    ): Predicate {
        check(arg != null) { "Cannot compare null arguments" }
        check(checkIfComparableOfSameType(arg)) { "${arg.javaClass} is not a comparable of his same type" }

        val castedArg = arg as Y
        return when (operator) {
            GREATER_THAN -> greaterThan(root.get(property), castedArg)
            GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL -> greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(property), castedArg)
            LESS_THAN -> lessThan(root.get(property), castedArg)
            LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL -> lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(property), castedArg)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected operator")
        }
    }
```